# pyinstaller error - AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'freeze_includes'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to make my python file to exe file, though I got an error.
I tapped `pyinstaller -w file.py` in my cmd screen,
then I got an error like below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 92, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
213, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line
161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
472, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410
, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377
, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 728, in impor
tlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrappe
r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 251, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 675, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pytest.py", line 16
, in <module>
    hiddenimports = pytest.freeze_includes()
AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'freeze_includes'
```

I added `import pytest` in my python file, but there's no change.
Please let me know about the error.

Comment: can you try 'import pytest` followed by `pytest.freeze_includes()` in python shell terminal\command prompt?

Answer (score 10):

This issue is caused by an out of date version of pytest. I was able to resolve it by using `pip uninstall pytest` and `pip install pytest` one after the other to update to the lastest version of pytest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the update proposed by Jacob didn't really help because other requirements were violated. I didn't need pytest in my program, so I just deleted the pytest hook from the PyInstaller. The path for me was

```
C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pytest.py
```

So not really a "solution", but still works for me.